# What's the best way to call the Cloud File API from a C# WinRT component?

Tags: winapi, interop, dllimport, dllexport

The Cloud File Api from this [Cloud Sync Engine Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine) is a Win32 Api. I've read that you can call C++ functions in C# using `__declspec(dllexport)...` and was wondering if that could be done for the `cfapi.h` header. It seems to have some deep underlying structs that it depends on, so I have no idea how complicated it would be. For example, `CfCreatePlaceholders()` takes in a `CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO` struct as a parameter, would I also need to dllexport a structure like that too? If so, then if that struct then takes another struct, it quickly becomes a very deep hole.

Is this even the best path to take? Are there alternative methods? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider?view=winrt-22000

Comment: I've skimmed through this briefly, but didn't find any functions for creating placeholders. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) is the latest and greatest in consuming the Windows API from C#. *"Are there alternative methods?"* - Sure. Implement a WinRT component in C++ that captures access to the Cloud Filter API. A WinRT component written in C++ is immediately available to C# code.

Comment: Indeed, there's no WinRT API for the engine part of the low-level Cloud File API, only for its registration part, so there's nothing "easily" accessible from C#. So, you can 1) use C#/Win32 (note it requires your .NET code to be marked as unsafe) where the Cloud File API will appear in the Windows.Win32.Storage.CloudFilters namespace, or 2) use p/invoke and do it all by yourself (or copy the juicy parts from what C#/Win32 generates), or 3) use an intermediary native (C/C++/Delphi, etc.) component callable from C#.

Comment: I've never heard of C#/Win32, but from the little reading I've done, it might be exactly what I need. I'll have to research it a bit more to tell. From what I've seen, it seems like it uses win32 dlls (is this correct?). If so, is there already a feature to use C#/Win32 on third party dlls? Thanks people!